# C# HTML Agility Pack with IF statement

Tags: c#, html-parsing, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

I have this code that I need to run an if statement to set the value of a variable.  The problem is when the first condition is null it fails.  Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

The IF statement is inside the foreach loop which adds a value to a list on each iteration.

Thank you very much!

```
 string result = string.Empty;

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Method = "GET";

        using (var stream = request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            result = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }

        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        doc.Load(new StringReader(result));
        HtmlNode root = doc.DocumentNode;

        string itemdesc = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//h1[@class='producttitle']").InnerText;

        HtmlNodeCollection nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='resultsset']/table/tbody[@class='result']/tr");

        List<string> sellers = new List<string>();
        List<string> prices = new List<string>();

        foreach (HtmlNode node in nodes)
        {
            string seller = string.Empty;
                if(node.SelectSingleNode(".//ul[@class='sellerInformation']/img").GetAttributeValue("alt", string.Empty) != null)
                {
                    seller = node.SelectSingleNode(".//ul[@class='sellerInformation']/img").GetAttributeValue("alt", string.Empty);
                }

                else if (node.SelectSingleNode(".//ul[@class='sellerInformation']/a/img").GetAttributeValue("alt", string.Empty) != null)
                {
                    seller = node.SelectSingleNode(".//ul[@class='sellerInformation']/a/img").GetAttributeValue("alt", string.Empty);
                }

                else
                {
                    seller = node.SelectSingleNode(".//ul[@class='sellerInformation']/li/div/span/a/b").InnerText;
                }


            sellers.Add(seller);
            string price = node.SelectSingleNode(".//span[@class='price']").InnerText;
            prices.Add(price);

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably `SelectSingleNode` is returning null, so the call to `GetAttributeValue` is a null reference problem. You will need to check the result of `SelectSingleNode` before checking the attribute.